# extending html form element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, custom-element

First time trying to extend a specific html element, in my case a form. I have some experience with "normal" custom elements / web components, derived from HTMLElement.

The base code for demo purposes:

```
customElements.define('my-form', class extends HTMLFormElement {
    constructor() {
        console.log('my-form()');
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('my-form::cc()');
        super.connectedCallback();
    }
}, {extends: 'form'});
```

If I insert the new element as `<my-form>[form content]</my-form>`, the element will be an instance of `HTMLElement`, but not an instance of `HTMLFormElement`, from which it was derived. Why? Also the code in `constructor()` and `connectedCallback()` are never called. Why ? It is definitely not a form, because it doesn't have the .elements propriety.

Using  `<form is="my-form">` seems to work somehow, constructor and cc() are called, the object is an instance of `HTMLFormElement`, the only error I get is `TypeError: (intermediate value).connectedCallback is not a function at HTMLFormElement.connectedCallback.`

Frankly I would prefer the first option (because in the second one I cannot use custom attributes and call it valid html). But what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: FYI, Customized Built-In Elements (anything but HTMLElement) will never be supported in Apple browsers

Comment: heil safari, the new internet exploder :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form is="my-form">` is the correct **and only** notation for a **Customized Built-In Element** (extends HTMLFormElement)

`<my-form>` is the notation for an **Autonomous Element** (extends HTMLElement)

The latter is the only version of Custom Elements supported in Safari. Apple have, since 2016, stated they will never implement Customized Built-In Elements.

`HTMLFormElement` does NOT have a `connectedCallback` method; that is why you get an error when you call that method on the `super` Element.

If you extend from HTMLFormElement and you use `<my-form>` it is in no way related to your definition; you create an HTMLUnknownElement, which by default **is** an HTMLElement.